# Como fazer uma verificação de duplicação de e-mail no método Put (update) quando algum outro usuário já tem o mesmo e-mail cadastrado?

Tags: node.js, ionic, back-end

No back-end da aplicação em node, quero fazer uma verificação de e-mail quando algum outro usuário já tem o mesmo e-mail cadastrado. Já funciona bem quando utilizo com o método POST, porém, ao fazer um update com PUT, a rotina atual identifica o próprio e-mail do usuário a ser alterado como duplicado (por ele já estar cadastrado no banco de dados), não queria isso e nem faz sentido, gostaria que no update, não fosse considerado o e-mail do próprio usuário que estou alterando, mas sim, verificar se tem algum outro usuário com e-mail equivalente.

Tentei o seguinte código:

```
chekEmailDuplicate = (req, res) => {
   User.findOne({//Tenta localizar algum usuário
            where: {//onde
                   id: !req.body.id,
                email: req.body.email
            }
        }).then(user => {
            if (user) {
                res.status(400).send("Fail -> Email is already in use!");
                return;
            }
}
```

Como podemos observar no código acima, em:

```
id: !req.body.id
```

Tentei algo como considerar o id diferente do próprio usuário em modificação, porém NÃO funciona, a aplicação aceita duplicidade de e-mail do mesmo jeito! No POST é uma maravilha, mas com o PUT não vai.

Alguém que manja em Node ou já sabe como resolver poderia me ajudar? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Resolvido por mim mesmo na resposta abaixo!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver aqui :) Utilizei o sequelize.op, onde declarei uma variável:

```
const Op = db.sequelize.op
```

O trecho que utilizei ficou assim: 
`id:{[Op.ne]: req.body.id}`

Abaixo, uma lista com todos os possíveis operadores do sequelize.

```
Project.findAll({
  where: {
    id: {
      [Op.and]: {a: 5},           // AND (a = 5)
      [Op.or]: [{a: 5}, {a: 6}],  // (a = 5 OR a = 6)
      [Op.gt]: 6,                // id > 6
      [Op.gte]: 6,               // id >= 6
      [Op.lt]: 10,               // id < 10
      [Op.lte]: 10,              // id <= 10
      [Op.ne]: 20,               // id != 20
      [Op.between]: [6, 10],     // BETWEEN 6 AND 10
      [Op.notBetween]: [11, 15], // NOT BETWEEN 11 AND 15
      [Op.in]: [1, 2],           // IN [1, 2]
      [Op.notIn]: [1, 2],        // NOT IN [1, 2]
      [Op.like]: '%hat',         // LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.notLike]: '%hat',       // NOT LIKE '%hat'
      [Op.iLike]: '%hat',         // ILIKE '%hat' (case insensitive)  (PG only)
      [Op.notILike]: '%hat',      // NOT ILIKE '%hat'  (PG only)
      [Op.overlap]: [1, 2],       // && [1, 2] (PG array overlap operator)
      [Op.contains]: [1, 2],      // @> [1, 2] (PG array contains operator)
      [Op.contained]: [1, 2],     // <@ [1, 2] (PG array contained by operator)
      [Op.any]: [2,3]            // ANY ARRAY[2, 3]::INTEGER (PG only)
    },
    status: {
      [Op.not]: false           // status NOT FALSE
    }
  }
})
```

Mais informações em: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/models-usage.html